# XBox 360 RCA Speaker volume

Tags: xbox-360

I have my XBox 360 connected to my PC Monitor via HDMI. The problem is that my Acer S240HL monitor does not have any audio output of any kind.

I have already pulled the casing off of the original composite connector, thus I can connect both HDMI and composite at the same time (with a bit of tape to block the video circuit)
I also have an adapter which converts the two male RCA audio outputs to a single female 3.5mm headphone socket.

This setup enables me to connect headphones/pc speakers to the xbox.

My problem is that the volume of the sound is too low to be usable.

---

I am pretty sure that some (all?) Turtle Beach models can use the RCA audio output with an [adapter like this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/RCA-Audio-Cable-Adaptor-compatible/dp/B004S5EH6Q/ref=sr_1_67?ie=UTF8&qid=1379781736&sr=8-67&keywords=rca+adapter) and presumably they work. So is it that the adapter is different from the standard composite connector that I am using, or that the headphones provide their own amplification.

If it is the latter, what can I add to my setup to amplify the output without having to spend a fortune?

Is there some easier way to get the sound to my pc speakers?

---

If amplification is the only way, [is this the sort of thing that would work](http://www.richersounds.com/product/phono-pre-amps/btech/bt26-pre-amp/b-te-bt26prea)? (I envision connecting something like this between the RCA outputs and my headphones RCA -> amp -> RCA adapter -> Headphones)

Comment: Does your monitor have a 3.5 out? My monitors have them even though they have no speakers for just such an occasion.

Comment: No, there is no audio output at all.

Comment: Sounds like you need an amp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've tried a few things and got the sound working at an acceptable level.

In short, **amplification is required**...

---

I found an interesting question, and very detailed answer over on [Super User](https://superuser.com/a/497229/216439) The answer talks about a Java app called [Audio Compressor & Limiter](http://www.hotto.de/software/audiocompressorlimiter.html).

With the help of the guide in the aforementioned answer, I managed to get audio at a usable volume (though with a noticeable hiss) by connecting the RCA out from the Xbox directly to the line in on my sound card (via an RCA to 3.5mm jack adapter).

---

The sound level from software amplification alone is only just usable, so I decided to take a chance on an RCA Pre-Amp.

I found [this one on amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B005ES0KJY/ref=oh_details_o03_s00_i00?ie=UTF8&psc=1), designed for use as a pre-amp for turntables, and it was well worth the risk.

One end is connected to the RCA output on the Xbox and the other connects directly to my PC speakers. This setup requires volume control on speakers and the volume is not going to split any ears, but it's fine for me.

Also, the combination of Pre-Amp and Audio Compressor & Limiter should stretch my speakers to their limits.

---

I hope this helps someone